# Como usar PhantomJS para acessar uma API com resposta em JSON

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

Como usar `PhantomJS` para acessar uma API cuja resposta seja `JSON` e não HTML e processar o resultado?

Gostaria que no exemplo fosse usado a própria API do Stackoverflow em português, de modo que o script retornasse o título e os nomes dos autores de questões recentemente alteradas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso, vá na inteface da API e descubra qual URL deve usar. Para este caso específico, este é o link direto https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/no-answer-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=pt.stackoverflow&run=true

O código abaixo abaixo está documentado e detalha como fazer isso

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

// Acesse perguncas recentes do pt.stackoverflow
page.open('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/no-answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=pt.stackoverflow', function () {
    var objeto = null, i = 0;

    try {
        // page.plainText retorna o conteúdo da página pura, sem forçar tags HTML em volta e invalidar a resposta como JSON
        objeto = JSON.parse(page.plainText);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Erro ao processar resposta em JSON');
    }
    if (objeto && objeto.items && objeto.items.length) {
        for (i = 0; i < objeto.items.length; i +=1) {
            console.log(objeto.items[i].title + ' por ' + objeto.items[i].owner.display_name);
        }
    }
    phantom.exit(); // Finaliza
});
```

Ele irá imprimir algo como

```
java.lang.NullPointerException em sistema de chat por Luiz
Como trabalhar OO com Banco de Dados no Delphi? por Arthur de Andrade
Como criar uma AVD para Android em Delphi por Luiz
(...)
```